# Data doesn't show in the work environment

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, show

I have successfully merged two dataframes, but for some reason it does not show up.
This is the code i used:

```
final_data %>% left_join(aid_data, by = c("country_name"="Country"))
```

It shows in the console how the new merged dataframe looks like, but it doesn't appear under `final_data` in the environment or when i do `view()` or `head()` etc.

I didn't get any errors on merging.

Why might this be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your datafame "final_data" is not updated by your code.

It should be something like

```
final_data <- final_data %>% left_join(aid_data, by = c("country_name"="Country"))
```

or create a new data.frame object

```
merged_data <-left_join(final_data, aid_data, by = c("country_name"="Country"))
```

I don't see much reason to use %>% in this code.